# How to call a view within a ViewController?

Tags: swift, uiview, xib

I have a view, named `IndicatorView`, a subclass of `UIView`. I have a `xib` file for this view as well. I'd like to call this view in my ViewController using `UITapGestureRecongnizer`, which I have been able to do. My problem lies in how to call the view when I tap. What code should be added to my `UIView` file so that I can call it from the `xib` file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an object from a xib file programatically you can use: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXibName" owner:self options:nil]`.

Now, in your click event of `UITapGestureRecongnizer` add the following code.

**ObjC**

```
IndicatorView *objIndicator = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IndicatorView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:objIndicator];
```

**Swift 3**

```
var objIndicator: IndicatorView? = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("IndicatorView", owner: self, options: nil)[0]
self.view.addSubview(objIndicator)
```

**Note**: You can pass the view on which you want to add at the place of self.view

Comment: But why are you create two views, `rootView` and `myVIew`?

Comment: If it not much of a problem, could you please give it in swift?

Comment: Okay, I am updating the same.

Comment: The app seems to crash, giving this in the logs `reason: '[<gesturerecognizer.ViewController 0x7fcc6ad088f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key testLabel.'` testLabel is a label in that view. Is there anything which I need to add in the `IndicatorView.swift` file?

Comment: Please check IBOutlet of testLabel.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to call the view. I've edited a small portion as it was not working without changing it. Hope its fine. Thanks again.